# Protect from injections and right syntax for $_GET method

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

So, I am trying to use the get method while protecting from injections. I'm trying to get data from the database and echo it out to a page. I think it's pretty obvious what I'm trying to do with the code below but i need help with using the right syntax.

Can someone show me the right syntax for the prepare statement to get data from a database using mysqli that is protected from injections?

I've looked on this site can't seem to find what I'm looking for and the PHP site I couldn't find an up to date method. Thanks for all the help.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("", "", "", "");
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_error . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

if($stmt->prepare("SELECT 'name,name' FROM 'table' WHERE 'name, name' = ?,?")) {
}

if (!$stmt->bind_param('si', $_GET['name'], $_GET['name'])); {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->error . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->error . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->fetch()); {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->error . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

$stmt->close();
?>
```

Comment: What does this `'name,name'` supposed to mean?

Comment: just an example for rows im trying to get information from is what 'name, name' is

Comment: Just a side note: You probably want that to read "SELECT name, name FROM table WHERE ..."

Comment: ok thank you but the code is correct for protecting from injections? Ill switch that to see if I made a simple mistake.

Comment: It is correct. bind_param escapes for you, so no problem there, but your query is wrong: `SELECT name FROM table WHERE name = '?' OR name = '?'` would be right.

Comment: im getting a bind parameter error for syntax

Comment: ill try the quoting the ?. I can use multiple rows for select and where right?

Comment: @bwoebi : I am glad that I did not alone overlooked the `;` in the OP's code . `if (!$stmt->bind_param('si', $_GET['name'], $_GET['name'])); {`

Comment: @moskito-x Effectively :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your sql is wrong:

```
if($stmt->prepare("SELECT 'name,name' FROM 'table' WHERE 'name, name' = ?,?")) {
```

must be

```
if($stmt->prepare("SELECT name, name FROM table WHERE name=? AND name=? ")) {
```

Double the expressive `name`, I used only because of the question.

The following is clearer:

```
if($stmt->prepare("SELECT astring, ainteger FROM table WHERE astring=? AND ainteger=? ")) 
{
if (!$stmt->bind_param('si', $_GET['astring'], $_GET['ainteger'])) {
```

Take out some time to write the question carefully. If two variables are used, then designate different, everything else just confused.

**Update :**

- Before you use `bind_param()`
- You have to test all $_GET["xx"].

`if (isset($_GET['name']))`

- When you call a function, terminated with `;` for example:

`if (!$stmt->bind_param('si', $_GET['name'], $_GET['name'])); {`

Then the curly braces are useless, no matter the `if` gets `true` or `false`!

The following code after `if (!$stmt->bind_param(...));` will always be executed, because the command, is finished.

```
if (!$stmt->bind_param('si', $_GET['name'], $_GET['name'])); {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->error . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```

It took a long time until I found this error. It is easily overlooked.

**That's why you always get your own error messages.**

Comment: Everything works fine except I get `bind_param` failed error. This is what the code looks like. `if (!$stmt->bind_param('si', $_GET['name'], $_GET['int'])); {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->error . ") " . $stmt->error;
}` any idea how to fix? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement. This turning out to be a pain. haha.

Comment: instead of `bind_param` do you think getting rid of that code and using `mysqli_real_escape_sting()` for each would solve the problem?

Comment: same result the parameters still fail. Thank you for helping thus is beyond me.

Comment: Note : I delete all my comments and put it into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

to protect from sql injection, you should first make a connection to your mysql database and after that you should surround your $_GET with mysql_real_escape_string(), like this:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])
```

or to use the newer function

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])
```

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` escpects two parameters. And `bind_params` does exactly the same as using it.

Comment: bwobi the current problem now is that I'm getting an invalid resource/object for `WHERE 'name,name = ?,?'`

Comment: but i dont get your mysql syntax, you are asking for two exact the same values, you ask for name twice. why?

Comment: I was just using that as an example. Sorry for the confusion, the first name is actual names and the second one is a numeric value.`if (!$stmt->bind_param('si', $_GET['name'], $_GET['name']));` they aren't actually called name name. notice `si`

Comment: maybe you can first assign mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']) to a variable and then use that variable in your code.

Comment: `bind_params` does the same thing I'm look for correct syntax now for `if($stmt->prepare("SELECT 'name,name' FROM 'table' WHERE 'name, name' = ?,?")) {
}
`keep getting syntax error

Answer (score 0):

This is better solution if you whant to protect all GET inputs:

```
function GET($name=NULL, $value=false)
{
    $content=(!empty($_GET[$name]) ? trim($_GET[$name]) : (!empty($value) && !is_array($value) ? trim($value) : false));
    if(is_numeric($content))
        return preg_replace("@([^0-9])@Ui", "", $content);
    else if(is_bool($content))
        return ($content?true:false);
    else if(is_float($content))
        return preg_replace("@([^0-9\,\.\+\-])@Ui", "", $content);
    else if(is_string($content))
    {
        if(filter_var ($content, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
            return $content;
        else if(filter_var ($content, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            return $content;
        else if(filter_var ($content, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
            return $content;
        else if(filter_var ($content, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT))
            return $content;
        else
            return preg_replace("@([^a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\_\*\@\$\!\;\.\?\#\:\=\%\/\ ]+)@Ui", "", $content);
    }
    else false;
}
```

Just instead $_GET['something'] you use GET('something') and you have option to put default value if GET value don't exists. And lather in MySQL query you can use escape string or prepared state to full protect your query.