# What is the right syntax for MySQL injection security for $_GET[] and wildcard

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

This one came close to answering my question: [Protect from injections and right syntax for $_GET method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153676/protect-from-injections-and-right-syntax-for-get-method)

However, my issue is that I am trying to combine the wildcard search %. So my original statement that works is like this which is wrapped in a try catch block.

```
    $sql = "SELECT id, Store_name, address_line_1, city, state FROM pharmacies_weno WHERE Store_name LIKE '%".$_GET['term']."%' AND city LIKE '%".$_GET['city']."%'";
    $sql .= " AND address_line_1 LIKE '%".$_GET['address']."%'";
```

But of course I want to make the statement like this.

```
    $sql = "SELECT id, Store_name, address_line_1, city, state FROM pharmacies_weno WHERE Store_name LIKE ? AND city LIKE ?;
    $sql .= " AND address_line_1 LIKE ? ";
```

With a statement like this 
       $stm = ('%$term%','%$city%','%$address%');

However, this is not working. I have tried all the variations of double and single quotes that I can think of along with the concatenation but nothing is working for me. I put the $_GET variables into another variable.

Yes there is other code in the program that does the binding. The final statement should look something like.

```
    $sql = "SELECT id, Store_name, address_line_1, city, state FROM pharmacies_weno WHERE Store_name LIKE ? AND city LIKE ?;
    $sql .= " AND address_line_1 LIKE ? ";
    $stm = ('%$term%','%$city%','%$address%');

    sqlStatement($sql,$stm);  //This is where the binding takes place in the program
```

So what I need to know is how to use the wildcard with the variable.

Comment: Use `[]` to define arrays, not `()`. Or use `array()`.

Comment: you are so right I was looking in the wrong direction and for got the array() function. So it should be $stm = array('%'.$term.'%','%'.$city.'%','%'.$address.'%')

Comment: `LIKE` doesn't accept an array. Your query will have to read `LIKE ? OR ... LIKE ? OR ...` for starters.

Comment: "I have tried all the variations of double and single quotes" - Well, just learn [the difference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), it isn't that hard and it'll save you a lot of time in the future ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using PDO then i would like to do like-

```
$sql = "SELECT id, Store_name, address_line_1, city, state FROM pharmacies_weno
            WHERE Store_name LIKE :store_name 
                  AND city LIKE :city
                  AND address_line_1 LIKE :address_line_1 ";
// now prepared statement like-
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(
                     ':store_name'=>'%'.$_GET['store_name'].'%',
                     ':city'=>'%'.$_GET['city'].'%',
                     ':address_line_1'=>'%'.$_GET['address_line_1'].'%'
                    ));
$result=$stmt->fetchAll();
```

if you didnot use pdo then have a look over [pdo prepared statement via php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)